# How to use putExtra to open another app and send some data for it?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, deep-linking

I have two apps (A, B) that I want to link them together.
When the user is in app A, by clicking on a button I want to open app B and send some data to it.

I used this method in app A to go app B and send some data to app B:

```
public static boolean openApp(Context mContext, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent goToEncyclopedia = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (goToEncyclopedia == null) {
        return false;
    }
    goToEncyclopedia.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    goToEncyclopedia.putExtra("NAME" , "Ehsan");
    context.startActivity(goToEncyclopedia);

    return true;
}
```

and I Call it like this in app A:

```
openApp(mContext, "encyclopedia.rasad.app.codenevisha.com.encyclopedia");
```

When I call this method it will open app B but data that I want to send with putExtra will not send.

And this is my code in App B to receive data from intent:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null){
    String name = bundle.getString("NAME");
    Log.i("EXTRAS", name);
}
```

Comment: as I see, you send a launcher intent to the package. Try to send an intent directly to the activity. Maybe that's why your data is getting lost somewhere.

Comment: when I change intent to activity directly, even app B will not open

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add intent filter in app **B**:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.yourpackage.action" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Pass data from app **A**:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourpackage.action");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("data","data string");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve data from app **B**:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple solution, It works very well

Answer (score 3):

**Answer 1**

In App A use `Bundle` to send data to App B

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("NAME" , "Ehsan");
goToEncyclopedia.putExtras(bundle);
```

**Answer 2**

Remove below line of `code`

```
goToEncyclopedia.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Final code will be
 **App A**

```
Intent sendIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app2");
sendIntent.putExtra("NAME", "Ehsan");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**App B**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent.hasExtra("NAME")) {
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("NAME");

}
```