# how do I transfer a variable from Home Activity to another project file

Tags: android, kotlin

do I have var searchText = et_search_field?.text?.toString() in my HomeActivity
And I need to pass $search Text to "https://t.supersimplesearch1.com/searchm ?q=$searchText&n=9250
But I can 't do it in any way because I can't call this variable in another class

```
   private fun onSearchClicked() {
    val searchText = et_search_field?.text?.toString()

    if (!searchText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        if (searchText.contains(".") && !searchText.contains(" ")) {
            requestToWeb =
                if (searchText.startsWith("http://") ||
                    searchText.startsWith("https://"))
                    searchText
                else "http://$searchText"

            createHttpTask(requestToWeb!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    isSiteAvailability = true
                    startActivity(
                        BrowserActivity.newIntent(
                            this,
                            requestToWeb,
                            isSiteAvailability = isSiteAvailability
                        )
                    )
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    requestToWeb = requestToWeb!!.replace("http://", "")
                    isSiteAvailability = false
                    if (it.message == "Error: 301") {
                        requestToWeb = "https://$requestToWeb"
                        createHttpTask(requestToWeb!!)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                isSiteAvailability = true
                                startActivity(
                                    BrowserActivity.newIntent(
                                        this,
                                        requestToWeb,
                                        isSiteAvailability = isSiteAvailability
                                    )
                                )

                            }
                            .addOnFailureListener {
                                requestToWeb = requestToWeb!!.replace("https://", "")
                                isSiteAvailability = false
                                startActivity(
                                    BrowserActivity.newIntent(
                                        this,
                                        requestToWeb,
                                        isSiteAvailability = isSiteAvailability
                                    )
                                )
                            }

                    } else {
                        startActivity(
                            BrowserActivity.newIntent(
                                this,
                                requestToWeb,
                                isSiteAvailability = isSiteAvailability
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
        } else {
            isSiteAvailability = false
            requestToWeb = searchText
            startActivity(
                BrowserActivity.newIntent(
                    this,
                    requestToWeb,
                    isSiteAvailability = isSiteAvailability
                )
            )
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.search_empty_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

this is in homeactivity

I globalized this variable , but that didn 't help either

Comment: Please refer this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433120/how-to-use-putextra-to-open-another-app-and-send-some-data-for-it

Answer (score 0):

- You can send data from one Activity to an other in the Intent

  val intent = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java)
  intent.putExtra("myKey", YOUR_DATA)
  startActivity(intent)

You can put data who implements Seriablizable or you can serialise/deserialise your data in JSON to have String for exemple with GSON.

- You can use EventBus

With Otto https://square.github.io/otto/ or GreenRobot https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
Your activity post data in the bus and other file can listen the bus and receive the data. Just don't forgot to unlisten the bus.

- Global value

You can create global variable

```
object MyGlobalData {
   var name = "toto
}
```

Use everywhere

```
MyGlobalData.name = "titi"
```

- You can use Listener

Create interface with method and your activity will call them and the other class will listen

```
interface MyHomeActivityListener {
    fun doSomeAction(val someData: String)
}
```

In your activity

```
var activityListener : MyHomeActivityListener? = null
```

and When you want send your data

```
activityListener?.doSomeAction(YOUR_DATA)
```

In the other class

```
refToYouractivity.activityListener {
    println("Receive data : $it")
}
```

Take care of memory leaks with this option.